# Strange output printing char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

### human header

```
class human
{    
    char name[];    
    public:

    void setName(char nameValue[]);
    char* getName();
}
```

### human cpp

```
void human::setName(char nameValue[])
{    
    char name[] = "walter";         
}

char* human::getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

### main cpp

```
int main()
{
    human myHuman;
    char name[] = "walter";
   
    myHuman.setName(name);
    char* result3 = myHuman.getName();
     
    cout << "My human has a name of " << result3 << endl;
   
    return 0;   
}
```

I assign the string `"walter"` but when I print it I get "╠╠╠╠╦ß╩d└²╒".

I don't understand which part is wrong. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please use `std::string`

Comment: i cannot. it is homework. pls help me with char

Comment: There are many errors in your program. The worst one is using `char*` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: @bkk before we give you help this is no good to you; please update the question with the requirements/restrictions from your homework.

Comment: @bkk _"i cannot. it is homework"_ Probably the reason for this homework ist to show you that's incredibly hard to deal with simple char arrays in c++, and `std::string` solves all of that smoothly for you. So the major goal is to show you what pain it is. Mission accomplished.

Comment: `char name[];` is a _flexible array_  - It's C code. It doesn't exist in (standard) C++ (but perhaps some implementations has it as an extension). If you can't use `std::string`, try writing a `std::string`-like class yourself. It's a good exercise.

Comment: setName implementation is confusing to me. You are assigning a constant name to the new char name [] variable name.
1) change the char name [] definition in header file to char * name. 2) assign nameValue (input of setName to same "name" variable). DO not redefine a new char name[] inside setName().

Comment: @Ashkanxy i am soooo appraciate you. it does work. thank you so much :) finally :)
i just edit the header file to char* and worked

Comment: @bkk With that change only, your class will point at an external character array. If that array goes out of scope and is destroyed, the pointer in your class will be dangling. Dereferencing it will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @TedLyngmo actually i have a problem with visiul studio. it doesnt give recent output everytime. i tried to different things and after that change still it gave output same. but after that gave error. again i am stuck with that code

Comment: @bkk If you go for `char*` you will probably need to allocate memory and copy the C string into the allocated memory. You need a destructor to free the memory and copy & move semantics to deal with resource ownership transfers. Since you will probably use strings quite a lot - writing such a class would help you a lot - until you're allowed to use `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost you are assigning `nameValue` to a variable local to the function `setName`, which means that the class variable `name` is still unitialized when you return it in `getName`, hence the strange output.

The `char name[];` declaration is also incorrect, C++ does not allow for variable length arrays or arrays with unspecified bounds unless they are immediately initialized in which case the size will be deduced given the size of the assigned string.

On that note, warnings must have been issued by your compiler, if not, crank them up, or better yet, make it treat warnings as errors, you'll have more robust code.

For the purpose of your assignment you should just go ahead and use pointers, a small problem arises because C++ does not allow for assignment of string literals to `char*` variables, this is easily fixed if you use `const char*`, your compiler may allow the former but it is illegal as per C++ rules.

Applying the corrections above, your code should look more like this:

```
class human
{
    const char* name;

public:
    void setName(const char *nameValue);
    const char* getName();
};

void human::setName(const char *nameValue)
{
  name = nameValue;
}

const char* human::getName(){
    return name;
}

int main()
{
    human myHuman;
    const char* name = "walter";
    myHuman.setName(name);
    const char* result3 = myHuman.getName();
    cout << "My human has a name of " << result3 << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: it works finally and i am for sure because i changed the name and still output give the recent one. thank you so much and now i just look at your code to understand to logic. you saved my homework